# Extremely slow GnuPG 2.x Performance

Tags: gnupg

I have an curious problem with my script. The script runs very fast ,when i use GnuPG 1.x. With GnuPG 2.x it runs very slow at encryption/decryption, and i have no idea why.

Versions: GnuPG 1.4.20-6 / GnuPG 2.1.11-7, both on Debian Testing x64

Commandlines:

```
gpg -z 0 --yes --no-tty --symmetric --cipher-algo twofish --digest-algo sha512 --passphrase-file $KEYFILE

gpg2 -z 0 --yes --batch --no-tty --symmetric --cipher-algo twofish --digest-algo sha512 --passphrase-file $KEYFILE
```

Both are working without any problems. Only the speed of GnuPG 2.x versus GnuPG 1.x is horrobly slow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Horribly slow" does not really fit a reasonable problem description. How large is your data set? How much time do GnuPG 1 and 2 require to finish encryption? For debugging purposes, remove the batch and no-tty options and add `-vv` for verbose output, and watch which steps take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

RNG seems to be depleted. If they're on the same host with the same libraries linked and built from source - then there's no other problem should be than RNG. It's especially visible/reproduceable if you're generating a long key: GPGv1 will be faster